# iOS storyboard how to autolayout image in LaunchScreen.storyboard exactly like in usual VC

Tags: ios, layout, autolayout, storyboard, constraints

I want to place an image into the LaunchScreen.storyboard viewController aswell as place the same image into my rootViewController in the normal storyboard. I want both screens look exactly the same.

But the image is not positioned the same if you use the same autolayout constraints. Might this be due to the statusbar at top which does not appear on launchscreen? How do i have to set up an image to look the same in both storyboard viewcontrollers?

Comment: Can you share screenshots about how both look now ? That would help understanding the problem better.

Comment: What happens if you copies the LaunchScreen.storyboard and without changing anything sets it's viewcontroller as "initial view controller" and as startup-view controller? Or the other way around. They should then be displayed exactly the same. I guess you have missed some property making them display differently.

Comment: it seems that the image inside the launchscreen was cached by xcode. therefore i could not see any changes i made.